# Wrapper that accepts both scalar and collection

Tags: c#

Can I somehow refactor this into one class? Some things are common here like Metadata property.

```
public class Resource<TEntity>
{
    public TEntity Data { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Metadata { get; set; }

    public Resource(TEntity data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }
}

public class ResourceCollection<TEntity>
{
    public ICollection<TEntity> Data { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Metadata { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }

    public ResourceCollection(ICollection<TEntity> data)
    {
        Data = data;

        Count = data.Count;
    }
}
```

Is this possible to make interface that expects either `ICollection<TEntity>` or `TEntity` alone?

This wrapper class is used for serialization it simply acts as a wrapper, but still I have some doubts about it that it could be done better

I also came up with this:

```
public class Resource<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Metadata { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public Resource(T data)
    {
        Data = data;

        if (data is ICollection collection)
        {
            Metadata["count"] = collection.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just use the first class? What is the benefit of using `ResourceCollection<Foo>` over `Resource<List<Foo>>`? (I'm not implying that there is no reason to do so, but I assume that you've omitted the code that would answer these questions). For CodeReview.SE, you should really be posting the full code, including usage (and and explanation of what you hope to achieve with the code)

Comment: I think it's mostly because it's easier to type. Also ResourceCollection adds Count property.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe I could do as you say but still I'd have to add Count somehow, probably in the Metadata.

Comment: The same question applies there again; what makes `myResourceCollection.Count` (in `ResourceCollection<Foo>`) better than `myResource.Data.Count` (in `Resource<List<Foo>>`)? Is the only argument here your preference of the syntax? Preferences are hard to objectively evaluate and review. I see no actual functional need for your second class, currently.

Comment: @Flater `Resource` is serialized to JSON on the server and returned to client(web API), Count is there so it can be serialized along the results so the client doesn't have to calculate it.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense. What would the `Count` of a resource be when it's not an IEnumerable? Fixed value 1? If you're asking to unify these classes, then you're obviously going to have a `Count` for all cases (whether it's a collection or not). You seem to be focusing on _how to do it_, but you still haven't actually shown a justification for _**why** you need to do it_, which should be the first step here.

Comment: @Flater Basically Count would have to be added only for collections and serve as a metadata describing this collection.

Comment: @Flater in my second example I have added a check if value is ICollection and based on that I'm adding `Count`

Comment: Given the updated code, what is the actual question you're asking here? It seems like you've already answered your own question, no?

Comment: @Flater it seems so

Comment: Happy to be your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)! ;)

Comment: @Flater lol that made me laugh

Comment: One thing that looks problematic is that all properties are publicly settable. Are you sure you want to allow any code to do `rc.Metadata = null`? And why do you need a `Count` property if you already have an `ICollection`? If you do need it, why doesn't it just return `Data.Count`, as Nikita's answer does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you could use inheritance if you really need that extra property:

```
public class ResourceCollection<TEntity> : Resource<ICollection<TEntity>>
{
    public ResourceCollection(ICollection<TEntity> data) : base(data)
    {
        //modify metadata if needed
    }

    public int Count => Data.Count;
}
```

While technically this is still two classes, you can now cast your collections to `Resource<T>` and process them in generic manner with your other resources.